# Using the youtube livestream API with a youtube partner channel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I remain perpetually stumped on this one.  I have a youtube channel, of which, I am an owner.  I have been using OAuth2 and authenticate to my owner account, then provide access to my youtube account with the following access domains

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
```

I issue the `youtube.liveStreams().list` command in the python google api interface with a variety of parameters but never do I get back a useful piece of information.

I currently have an unlisted stream running, DsjbycJHosw.

```
list_streams_request = youtube.liveStreams().list( part="snippet", id="DsjbycJHosw" )` responds with `{'etag': '"m2...gE"', 'kind': 'youtube#liveStreamListResponse', 'items': [], 'pageInfo': {'totalResults': 0, 'resultsPerPage': 5}}

list_streams_request = youtube.liveStreams().list( part="snippet", mine="true" )` responds with `{'etag': '"m2...gE"', 'kind': 'youtube#liveStreamListResponse', 'items': [], 'pageInfo': {'totalResults': 0, 'resultsPerPage': 5}}
```

`list_streams_request = youtube.liveStreams().list( part="snippet", broadcastStatus="all" )` gives me a python error.  Looks like the Python API doesn't support that. `TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "broadcaststatus`

```
list_streams_request = youtube.liveStreams().list( part="snippet", onBehalfOfContentOwner="[Channel Youtube UserID (base64)]" )` responds with `b'{\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "youtube.parameter",\n    "reason": "missingRequiredParameter",\n    "message": "No filter selected. Expected one of: mine, id, default",\n    "locationType": "parameter",\n    "location": ""\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 400,\n  "message": "No filter selected. Expected one of: mine, id, default"\n }\n}\n'
```

Ok, so, I need to give it something in conjunction with my channel's ID, right? Let's add a "mine"=true.

```
list_streams_request = youtube.liveStreams().list( part="snippet", onBehalfOfContentOwner="[Channel Youtube User ID(base64)]", mine="true" )` responds with `b'{\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "youtube.parameter",\n    "reason": "invalidMine",\n    "message": "The \\u003ccode\\u003emine\\u003c/code\\u003e parameter cannot be used in requests where the authenticated user is a YouTube partner. You should either remove the \\u003ccode\\u003emine\\u003c/code\\u003e parameter, authenticate as a YouTube user by removing the \\u003ccode\\u003eonBehalfOfContentOwner\\u003c/code\\u003e parameter, or act as one of the partners channels by providing the \\u003ccode\\u003eonBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel\\u003c/code\\u003e parameter if available for the called method.",\n    "locationType": "parameter",\n    "location": "mine"\n   }\n  ],\n  "code": 400,\n  "message": "The \\u003ccode\\u003emine\\u003c/code\\u003e parameter cannot be used in requests where the authenticated user is a YouTube partner. You should either remove the \\u003ccode\\u003emine\\u003c/code\\u003e parameter, authenticate as a YouTube user by removing the \\u003ccode\\u003eonBehalfOfContentOwner\\u003c/code\\u003e parameter, or act as one of the partners channels by providing the \\u003ccode\\u003eonBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel\\u003c/code\\u003e parameter if available for the called method."\n }\n}\n'
```

Really?  Come on now, Mr. API.  What about if I use `onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel`?

```
list_streams_request = youtube.liveStreams().list( part="snippet", onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel="[My base64 channel ID]" )` yeilds `b'{\n "error": {\n  "code": 500,\n  "message": null\n }\n}\n'
```

And every combination I can think of just gives me tons of error code 500's.

I also can't seem to set `forContentOwner` in the python API, so no dice there.  How is one supposed to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue.  As of Jan, 2018, they've resolved it.  The APIs behave exactly as expected as youtube partners can do the oauth permissions, now.